# How to search json structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm attempting to search through this json for a specific value.

I would like to search by the State value, such as 'NH' and get back the MaintenancePercentage and OfficePercentage.

I've tried looping through payrollDefaults.State and I'm getting back nothing.

```
var payrollDefaults =
    [
        {
            "State": "NH",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 21.45,
            "OfficePercentage": 22.56
        },
        {
            "State": "NC",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 21.79,
            "OfficePercentage": 22.41
        },
        {
            "State": "OH",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 21.33,
            "OfficePercentage": 22.25
        },
        {
            "State": "RI",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 23.04,
            "OfficePercentage": 23.22
        },
        {
            "State": "SC",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 21.31,
            "OfficePercentage": 31.33
        },
        {
            "State": "TX",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 35.6,
            "OfficePercentage": 24.48
        },
        {
            "State": "VA",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 32.32,
            "OfficePercentage": 30.47
        },
        {
            "State": "AL",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 13.33,
            "OfficePercentage": 12.42
        },
        {
            "State": "CA",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 49.37,
            "OfficePercentage": 59.67
        },
        {
            "State": "FL",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 34.62,
            "OfficePercentage": 31.06
        },
        {
            "State": "GA",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 35.55,
            "OfficePercentage": 30.29
        },
        {
            "State": "IN",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 33.45,
            "OfficePercentage": 30.69
        },
        {
            "State": "MA",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 32.9,
            "OfficePercentage": 29.34
        },
        {
            "State": "MI",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 34.95,
            "OfficePercentage": 29.46
        },
        {
            "State": "MT",
            "MaintenancePercentage": 35.91,
            "OfficePercentage": 30.02
        }
    ]
```

EDIT:

I ended up converting this from a string to JSON.

var json = $.parseJSON(payrollDefaults);

Comment: post some code dat u tried..

Comment: FYI: This isn't JSON.  It's a JavaScript array.  JSON is a *string representation* of data that resembles JavaScript syntax.  If it's not a string, it's not JSON.

Comment: `payrollDefaults.State` is not a value.  `payrollDefaults` is an array, loop through each element, and then check it's `.State` value.

Comment: That is indeed a JSON object. Notice that the keys are strings, i.e., `"State"`, `"MaintainancePercentage"`, `"OfficePercentage"`.

Comment: The code above shows a Javascript array. Also there's no such thing as a JSON object. http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja Each array element is actually a *JavaScript* object, not JSON. JSON = JavaScript Object *Notation*. JSON is a format to use within a string or file which can then be parsed by *the* JSON object to become a JavaScript object. The term "JSON object" is generally reserved for the native JavaScript object containing the methods for parsing JSON and stringifying JS objects (i.e. `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` respectively).

Comment: Also, JSON parse can verify whether a "structure" is valid JSON structure. Simple test:
   JSON.parse('[1,2,{"a":3}]');

If it was not valid, parse would throw error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick...

http://jsfiddle.net/6zn7H/

```
function findState(state) {
    for(var i =0, l = payrollDefaults.length; i < l; i++){
        var value = payrollDefaults[i];
        if(value.State === state){
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that this loop only evaluates the length once, and not on each iteration, helping efficiency.

Comment: Anyone want to justify their downvote? This answer works and addresses the question.

Comment: Happened to mine too. Strange. Your answer is more thorough so definitely didn't deserve it, but I don't think even mine was misleading or incorrect enough to warrant downvoting!

Comment: @guypursey Happens all over the place on SO. I think there's downvote ninjas whose sole boring purpose in life is to discredit correct answers in an attempt to undermine the system!

Answer (score 1):

You could use this JS lib, DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com) - which extends the global object JSON with the method "search". With this method, you can search a JSON structure with XPath expressions and it returns an array (empty if no matches were found).

```
var payrollDefaults = [
        { "State": "NH", "MaintenancePercentage": 21.45, "OfficePercentage": 22.56 },
        { "State": "NC", "MaintenancePercentage": 21.79, "OfficePercentage": 22.41 },
        { "State": "OH", "MaintenancePercentage": 21.33, "OfficePercentage": 22.25 },
        { "State": "RI", "MaintenancePercentage": 23.04, "OfficePercentage": 23.22 },
        { "State": "SC", "MaintenancePercentage": 21.31, "OfficePercentage": 31.33 },
        { "State": "TX", "MaintenancePercentage": 35.6,  "OfficePercentage": 24.48 },
        { "State": "VA", "MaintenancePercentage": 32.32, "OfficePercentage": 30.47 },
        { "State": "AL", "MaintenancePercentage": 13.33, "OfficePercentage": 12.42 },
        { "State": "CA", "MaintenancePercentage": 49.37, "OfficePercentage": 59.67 },
        { "State": "FL", "MaintenancePercentage": 34.62, "OfficePercentage": 31.06 },
        { "State": "GA", "MaintenancePercentage": 35.55, "OfficePercentage": 30.29 },
        { "State": "IN", "MaintenancePercentage": 33.45, "OfficePercentage": 30.69 },
        { "State": "MA", "MaintenancePercentage": 32.9,  "OfficePercentage": 29.34 },
        { "State": "MI", "MaintenancePercentage": 34.95, "OfficePercentage": 29.46 },
        { "State": "MT", "MaintenancePercentage": 35.91, "OfficePercentage": 30.02 }
    ],
    res = JSON.search( payrollDefaults, '//*[State = "NH"]' );

console.log( res[0].MaintenancePercentage );
console.log( res[0].OfficePercentage );
```

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/dMLdc/

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an index for the `payrollDefaults` array else your program won't know which specific object you want to pull the value of `State` from.

Just as an example, here's how to loop through all the `State` properties and print their values in the console.

```
for (var i = 0, l = payrollDefaults.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    console.log(payrollDefaults[i].State);
}
```

Notice the `[i]` and how that refers to a specific object in your array?

Hope that helps make sense of what you were missing!

Comment: Bad answer? I thought this addressed the main part of the question which I took to be: "I've tried looping through payrollDefaults.State and I'm getting back nothing." I didn't provide a solution because I figured the OP already had that bit nailed and was missing something simple...

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(payrollDefaults,function(key,val){
  if(val.state == "NH"){
   console.log(val.MaintenancePercentage);
   console.log(val.OfficePercentage);
  }

});
```

This should help you

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash.js](http://lodash.com/docs#find)'s find

```
_.find(payrollDefaults, {State: 'NH'});
>>> {
        "State": "NH",
        "MaintenancePercentage": 21.45,
        "OfficePercentage": 22.56
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below function:

```
function findByState(givenState) {
    var result = [];
    for(p in payrollDefaults) {
        if (p.State === givenState) {
            result.push(p);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you need to search for a particular state

```
function GetMaintainancePercentage(state) {
    for (var i = 0; i < payrollDefaults.length; i++) {
        if (payrollDefaults[i]["State"] == state) {
            alert('Maintainance Percenatge is ' + payrollDefaults[i]["MaintenancePercentage"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cAFfD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/ba5ZQ/1/

**JS:-**

```
var arr = jQuery.grep(payrollDefaults, function( a ) {
  return a.State =="NH";
});

console.log(arr);
```